# Limitar número de peticiones por persona

Tags: php, html, laravel

¿cómo están?

Tengo una página web programada con PHP(Laravel), pero está página es de pago por suscripción, o también gratuita. El usuario puede hacer uso del servicio 10 veces por día, y si quiere hacer más, puede pagar una suscripción premium.

El problema que tengo es que no logro limitar las veces que una persona puede hacer uso del servicio sin que se registren.

**He intentado lo siguiente:**

- Limitar por IP. He tratado que por IP solamente puedan hacer uso del servicio 10 veces, pero cuando ellos usan una VPN cambia, o tan solo conectarse a otra red.
- Uso de cookies. Ahora intenté con cookies, almaceno una cookie que va aumentando, y cuando el usuario llegó a el número 10 suelta un mensaje, pero esto se resuelve cuando el usuario borra cookies o usa navegador privado.

Tienen alguna idea de como podría hacer para que solo se pueda usar el servicio 10 veces por día sin que las personas se tengan que registrar en mi sitio web?

Comment: Es posible, pero cualquier método que no incluya alguna forma autenticación es proclive a fallar. Especialmente si el usuario es malintencionado y tiene habilidades técnicas.

Comment: Tu pregunta luce amplia y basada en opiniones lo cual generará su cierre

Comment: Mejor trabájalo con token, para que el usuario pueda usar el servicio, que meta su correo y le mandes el token sin necesidad de que se autentique a menos de que ya quiera pagar el servicio.